# How is a Firestore collection write limit imposed between different composite index query scopes?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

```
[collectionA]
    <someDocument>
        [subcollectionA]
            <someDocument>
                - lastActive: timestamp
                - joined: boolean
```

In this schema, `lastActive` is an indexed property, and it is sequential. Therefore, a write limit is imposed on `subcollectionA`. If I made a composite index of `lastActive` and `joined` on `subcollectionA`, I have the option to choose a query scope of **collection** and **collection group**. If I choose collection, the write limit is imposed on that specific subcollection instance, and if I choose collection group, then the write limit is imposed on all subcollections called `subcollectionA` as if they were one giant collection. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write limits are a physical limitation about how fast the indexes can be synchronized between the multiple data centers, before a write can be confirmed to the clients.

If you have a collection group query, the index needs to be updated for all collections in that group. So the limitation would then indeed apply to writes across all those collections.